# Vim and Latex-Suite - Syntax turns off after compile?

Tags: vim, latex

I'm using vim latex suite on windows, and i'm not sure why but after a compile a document, it seems many times the syntax highlighting in vim is turned off.  It's easily corrected with

```
:syntax on
```

but it is making my workflow less efficient...

It seems to happen more often when the compile to latex fails due to a syntax error.

Any tips appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How do you compile? Do you have any `autocmd`'s associated with tex files? Look through your vimrc for this. You can even do:

```
autocmd! BufRead *.tex syntax on
```

But that would be messy.

No matter your settings, I bet you can fix your compilation issues by using `arara`. Arara seems a bit overwhelming at first, but I assure you it's the best way to compile Latex with vim.

A simple setup of `arara`:
1. Add the arara executable to your path
2. Add this as 1st line of your file (or whichever flavour of tex you like):

```
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: on}
```

1. Add this mapping to your vimrc:

`nmap <F9> :update<CR> :cd %:p:h<cr>:pwd<cr> :!arara -v -l %<CR>`

Using advanced configurations you can even compile in the background(!) while you can continue to edit and browse your tex file.

Comment: I use arara with vim. How do you compile in the background? Thanks!

Comment: This strongly depends on your OS. I use Windows 7 together with ConEmu as my shell emulator. Basically you want to start a process, which Vim doesn't wait for until it's done. Using ConEmu does exactly that, it starts the compilation process asyncronously. There are vim plugins, which enable you to start processes in this way, f.e. xolox/vim-shell. In case you're on Windows, here's my ConEmu binding:

      nnoremap <buffer> <F9> :call SetWDToCurrentFile()<Bar>:update<Bar>silent! execute '!start C:/ConEmu/ConEmu.exe /cmd cmd /c arara -v -l -L de '.shellescape(@%, 1).' -new_console:c'<CR><CR>

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm on Windows and very interested on compiling asynchronously. If there are errors in the compilation process will the quickfix window be loaded with them?

Comment: No, as Vim is not designed to work asyncronously. You will have to wait for features like this one until neovim is finished. But take a deeper look into the async/shell plugins, shougo/vimshell is another one. You might find something interesting in there for you, if you're not quite happy with the ConEmu solution. I'm already happy being able to browse the code while it compiles.